# JavaScript game - How to control a children div from not moving outside of it's parent container

Tags: javascript

I started to build a simple JavaScript game this morning, I'm trying to figure out how I can control so that the div "box" can't be permitted to move outside of it's parent container? My guess would be with an if statement controlling the offsetLeft and offsetTop?

Javascript here:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var box = document.querySelector(".box");

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        var key = event.key;
        var left = box.offsetLeft;
        var top = box.offsetTop;
        var step = 10;

        switch (key) {
            case "ArrowUp":
                event.preventDefault();
                box.style.top = top - step + "px";
                break;
            case "ArrowDown":
                event.preventDefault();
                box.style.top = top + step + "px";
                break;
            case "ArrowLeft":
                event.preventDefault();
                box.style.left = left - step + "px";
                break;
            case "ArrowRight":
                event.preventDefault();
                box.style.left = left + step + "px";
                break;
        }
        console.log(event.key);
    });
    window.console.log("Sandbox is ready!");
})();
```

CSS here:

```
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    color: green;
}

.content {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 2em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

HTML below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Game</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Simple game</h1>
    <div id="content" class="content">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS and HTML coded added.

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/uwp0s9jz/

Comment: please add the html and css files here.

Comment: html and css added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `getBoundingClientRect()` to determine if you out of boundary I have updated the top and left for you as a start. You will need to factor in the `border-radius` if you want.

Fiddle updated: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jfy6gdzm/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Please see the code below.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var box = document.querySelector(".box");
    var container = document.getElementById('content').getBoundingClientRect()
    var paddingSize = 32
    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        var key = event.key;
        var left = box.offsetLeft;
        var top = box.offsetTop;
        var step = 10;

        switch (key) {
            case "ArrowUp":
                event.preventDefault();
                if (top > container.top + paddingSize) {
                    box.style.top = top - step + "px";
                }
                break;
            case "ArrowDown":
                event.preventDefault();
                if (top < container.height - container.x - paddingSize) {
                    box.style.top = top + step + "px";
                }
                break;
            case "ArrowLeft":
                event.preventDefault();
                if (left > container.left + paddingSize) {
                  box.style.left = left - step + "px";
                }
                break;
            case "ArrowRight":
                event.preventDefault();
                if (left < container.width - container.y - paddingSize) {
                  box.style.left = left + step + "px";
                }
                break;
        }
        console.log(event.key);
    });
})();
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Rihno/ekx61utq/)

Answer (score 0):

Use box parent offsets to determine the position of the box.
[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhtxrjay/15/)

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

  var box = document.querySelector(".box");
  var boxparent = document.querySelector(".content");
  var temp;
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event){
      var key = event.key;
      var left = box.offsetLeft;
      var top = box.offsetTop;
      var step = 10;
      event.preventDefault();

      switch (key) {
          case "ArrowUp":
              temp = top - step;
              if(temp > boxparent.offsetTop)
                  box.style.top = temp + "px";
              break;
          case "ArrowDown":
              temp = top + step;
              if((temp + step + step) < boxparent.offsetHeight)
                  box.style.top = top + step + "px";
              break;
          case "ArrowLeft":
              temp = left - step;
              if(temp > boxparent.offsetLeft)
                  box.style.left = left - step + "px";
              break;
          case "ArrowRight":
              temp = left - step;
              if((left + box.offsetWidth) < boxparent.offsetWidth)
                  box.style.left = left + step + "px";
              break;
      }
  });
})();
```

Comment: You forgot to define the variable temp

Comment: The case for ArrowRight is only working partly. It' doesn't let the div to reach the end of the container, but more like 60% of the container.